# Edit values in a table with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, edit, html-table

I'm very new to javascript and I need some help editing the content of a table cell.

For example, I would like to change the value of the matches won, drawn and lost to the percentage value in [**this page**](http://www.goal.com/en-us/results-standings/69/serie-a/table).

I'm not asking for the written code (but if you want, that isn't going to make me unhappy) but just for a link of a page explaining how to do it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up how to insert jQuery with greasemonkey can use the following which is tested on the page using a browser console:

```
$(function(){
    function percent_of_GP( gp, val){
       return parseInt( (100*val)/gp,10)
    }

    $('.teamStandings tbody tr').each(function(){
      var $cells=$(this).find('td')
       var gp=parseInt($cells.eq(4).text(),10) ;
       $cells.slice(5,14).each(function(){
          $(this).html(function(i, html){
            return percent_of_GP( gp,html)+'%'
          })
       });       
    });
});
```

Changes all Won/Lost/Drawn to percent in all 3 columns